# Networking: Connecting over subnets without changing subnet mask

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet

I have attached a picture of the network setup in my house, I would like to know how to make any device visible across all networks without changing the subnet mask which is 255.255.255.0. [image: Network Table]. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason you’ve set up that cascade of routers?

Comment: Change the ip's to 192.168.1.x -- that's the answer. I won't post an answer tho because 100 users will say it's wrong, but do that and you'll be done with this...

Comment: Routers, by their nature, have different IPs on their LAN and WAN side interfaces. I am assuming the addresses you've given for routers 2, 3 and 4 are their LAN side addresses and their WAN sides are all on the same subnet as router 1. If this is the case, then you should just be able to edit the routing table of router 1 such that it sends traffic for 192.168.2.255 out of the interface for router 2 and so on. Are you able to edit the routing table? Crazy set up though, I assume there's a good reason.